# Youtrack plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, youtrack

Is there any plugins for Eclipse that allow to work with Youtrack directly from the Eclipse?

I mean issues management.

Comment: I'd assume not as they'd want to push the intelliJ IDE

Answer (score 4):

here's the mylyn.connector: https://github.com/Amarchuk/youtrack.mylyn.connector/tree/gh-pages and here's the doc: http://jetbrains.github.io/youtrack.mylyn.connector/